# Datapoint on highmap slow down the Angular Application

Tags: javascript, angular, highcharts

Problem is when I am showing datapoints on map it is slowing down my page and when doing zoom in or zoom out on the map it is also slowing down my page, I mean it make my page unresponsive. please guide me how to handle this issue. Datapoints are upto 10,000 or maybe 50,000. I am also using boost and turbo threshold properties but still same behaviour.

Comment: Please reproduce a simplified demo of your issue which I will be able to work on.

Comment: @SebastianWędzel here is the demo link
https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-dirac-54pxt?file=/src/app/app.component.ts

Comment: 1. Have you considered to use the `markerCluster` feature? It could be a better way to display this amount of lat/long points. https://www.highcharts.com/demo/maps/marker-clusters
2. If you need to represent the data like this the only options which came to my mind to improve the performance are disabling the `animation` and `dataLabels`. Disabling these options speeds up working of the code a little bit. Demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/amazing-browser-4rzhy?file=/src/app/app.component.ts